# Loading in a tileset with c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a very large tileset with over 200 different 64x64 tiles. It would be practical to load them in a C# script, I've tried the following (for-loop):

```
tileset[x] = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Tileset/Tileset_" + x);
```

Where in my asset folder, `Sprites` is the folder where `Tileset.png` is. `Tileset.png` is sliced in a grid (64x64) in I see Unity has sliced all the tiles correctly.

Is there a way I can load them, and put them in a Sprite array (Sprite[]) in code? What would be the correct path?

Comment: So what's the actual problem?  Or are you asking if your method is the right way to do things?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for correctness? Then batching is caring...

If loaded individually, each tile will cost you a draw call. I would recommend that you look at creating spritesheets to batch the loading and rendering or these tiles. We have been using [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to load images for our apps and displaying 200+ images at once with one load call, one draw call and great performance. Alongside the app to create the spritesheets, there's a [Unity Plugin on the asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/8905) to load and manage them.

Note: we use the [pro version](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/8456).

Otherwise you can just load all the resources at a given path with [Resources.LoadAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html)